# Bullet points not showing in wordpress

Tags: css, editor, post-editor

Please I'm facing a problem with my blog, since the the bullet list points are not showing on my blogposts even though I always add them via the editor. [This is a direct link to a paragraph](https://shorturl.at/adoAC) with bullet points but they don't show up, so I used dash instead but still using the bullet points which don't appear, I also want the , sin ce the indentation doesn't appear neither.

Comment: Your shorturl doesn't work, but regardless, this is a CSS question, and so off topic here.

Comment: @vancoder This is the link, sorry I didn't notice that it didn't work at first : http://bit.ly/3QWn6qq If I can just know where I can have help concerning my question, I'll move it to the correct place. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Additional CSS for your theme, add the CSS code for 'list-style-type' for unordered list. Something like:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
```

Note that this will affect *all* unordered lists on your site.

Take a look at this page for other options: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp

**Added**

Note that your theme may be using additional CSS that could override the above setting. So you can try this to override the theme's overrides:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: circle !important;
}
```

You can also inspect the generated page code for a specific ID or CSS Class used.

Another option is to make a Child Theme, then look at the theme's styles.css file for the UL's CSS code, and copy that into your Child Theme's CSS file, then modify that.  This works because a Child Theme's CSS is loaded after the 'parent' theme's CSS file, so the Child Theme's CSS will override theme settings.

Note that you don't want to modify the theme's CSS file - a theme update will overwrite your changes.

Comment: I tried to add this code, but unfortunately it didn't work )': I also tried to look for the specific tags like adding .li and a. and after ul but didn't work also.

Comment: See additional info in my answer for some alternatives.